# ArrayList's contains() method always returns false with custom object

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I'm having some troubles with getting on with my code, I'll give you an simple example (though it's going to be a little more complex, this simple code doesn't work properly either).

```
class Sign {

  private String char;
  private Integer freq;

  public Sign(String c) {
  this.char = c; 
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {

   String check = (String)o;
   return check.equals(this.char);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {

    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.char.hashCode();
    return hash;
}

}
```

I assume that there's always will be a String in equals method for simplicity reasons. There's some hashCode() also to make sure that the contains() method will work and here's the test itself:

```
    ArrayList<Sign> queueOfSigns = new ArrayList<>();

    Sign test = new Sign("C");
    String c = "C";
    queueOfSigns.add(test);

    if(queueOfSigns.contains("C"))
        System.out.println("I am here!");
```

No matter what, this simple test-code always returns false in that case - so "I'm here" message never appears. I've been trying some different ways of approach my code but it was because the idea of this is to get single characters from String text and check whether the single character is already present in the ArrayList. Nevertheless - without getting this simple test working properly I can't move on, so I would like to ask you - what am I missing. It's my first time actually with using equals() and hashCode() methods to get my own object working properly with contains() method.

Comment: Most likely the issue is that `new Sign("C").equals("C")` does not return the same thing as `"C".equals(new Sign("C"))`. To work properly, `equals` needs to be symmetric: `a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)` should always be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) implementation is incorrect. `equals` has a specific contract; that code attempts to violate that contract. From the documentation:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is *reflexive*: for any non-`null` reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return `true`.
> - It is *symmetric*: for any non-`null` reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.
> - It is *transitive*: for any non-`null` reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.
> - It is *consistent*: for any non-`null` reference values `x` and `y`, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)` consistently return `true` or consistently return `false`, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-`null` reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

There's no way to make an instance of your `Sign` class `equals` to a string.

Comment: It's certainly *possible* to make an object report that it is equal to an object of another type. It just won't work *correctly* if the other object doesn't also make itself equal to your object. There are a few places where you can bend the rules (e.g. some projects have used dedicated "lookup objects" that are equal "enough", for exactly cases like this), but bending the rules is a very tricky proposition.

Comment: @DanielPryden - Right, and a useful observation. But `String`'s `equals` doesn't and isn't going to support the OP's `Sign` class, so... :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am pretty aware of these "relations" - the problem is that I just need, for my own reason, to have the actual String compared to my Sign object, even though they are not the same. I was just hoping that overriding equals() method is enough to cause the right comparation, considering that the ArrayList in this is "my-object-only". So any simple solution? Or is there at least any way to achive what I'm looking for? Better yet I would ask you about what should I type in Google just to find solution for my own. :)

Comment: For completeness, among those properties, the OP's `equals()` implementation exhibits only transitivity.  And where it's broken, it's *really* broken: it has a nasty habit of throwing `ClassCastException`s and `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It also exhibits consistency, doesn't it?

Comment: Technically no, @Sweeper.  There are lots of non-`null` object pairs for which the OP's `equals()` will throw a `ClassCastException` instead of returning either `true` or `false`.  But where it *does* return `true` or `false`, yes, it will do so consistently.

Comment: @LowProfile - I wouldn't use an `ArrayList` at all. I'd use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and store the `Sign` object using its `char` property as the key. Then you use `containsKey` to find out if the map has the object, or `get` to get the object based on the key.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah, didn't read the contract carefully enough... Consistency is defined as _always_ returning the same true or false.

Comment: @LowProfile, that your `ArrayList` is "my-object-only" is not really relevant to the situation.  Like the other Collections classes, `ArrayList` depends on elements to implement `equals(Object)` in a way that conforms to its documented contract.  Their own documented behavior is contingent on that.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - in the end I might use map - that was my first idea. I just wanted to have some tryout with arraylist and own equals(), hashCode().

Answer (score 1):

Your `equals` method is implemented incorrectly. It violates the general contract of [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

- It is not reflexive - since it throws an exception when the argument is not a string, `x.equals(x)` where `x` is a `Sign` will crash with an exception.
- It is not symmetric - `x.equals(y)` does not return the same value as `y.equals(x)`, if `y` is a string and `x` is a `Sign`
- It is not consistent - since it can possibly throw exceptions when the argument is not a string, not just return true or false.

On a low level of abstraction, the cause of this problem is the implementation of [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-). As per the docs:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

`ArrayList` actually calls `o.equals(e)` with `o` being the string you passed in. So it actually calls the `equals` method in `String`.

If `contains` called `e.equals(o)`, then your program would have printed "I'm here", but your `equals` still violates the contract.

A better `equals` implementation is something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (o.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
        Sign other = (Sign)o;
        return other.$char.equals($char); // I have renamed 'char' to '$char' since the former is not a valid identifier
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And your client code:

```
    ArrayList<Sign> queueOfSigns = new ArrayList<>();

    Sign test = new Sign("C");
    Sign c = new Sign("C");
    queueOfSigns.add(test);

    if(queueOfSigns.contains(c))
        System.out.println("I am here!");
```

EDIT:

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
arrayList.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getChar().equals("C"))
    .findFirst().isPresent() // this returns true if a sign with C is found in the array list
```

Comment: Even using `instanceof` in `equals` is dodgy. If I create a class `NiftySign` that extends `Sign`, a `NiftySign` instance isn't equal to a `Sign` instance, but `Sign'`s `equals` (per the above) would think it was.

Comment: Thanks, I get the problem, but the code won't do what I'm actually looking for. Here's the thing - I need to pass single letter (for example) as a String or a Character to contains() method of ArrayList - which has to contain Sign objects (ArrayList<Sign>). The problem persist, cause I just wanted to have my own, overridden equals() method that would actually compare String from Sign object to given String, like in the example. I just wanted to avoid "instanceof" because in my cause there is no way of passing anything alse - even though it's not a good practice in any way - I know.

Comment: Then you shouldn't override `equals`. You need to find an element in the array list that has a `char` field of `"C"`. See the edit. @LowProfile